# Input text questionnaire in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, input

I am trying to create a series of questions that are answered by input text. The user has the option to skip questions and when they answer correctly they advance to the next frame and new question.  The code is simple enough but for whatever reason when I remove the listener that validates the input and call a new one nothing happens and no errors are thrown.  I am away from my PC but will post the code if this doesn't make sense.

I am sure this could all be done on single frame but is beyond my skill, hence advancing to the next frame.

EDITTED: I have figured our the array piece and have it on one frame now but displayQuestion++; is not working....help!

```
var answerArray:Array=['uncle billy','six','178','hello4'];
var questionArray:Array=["what is the name of the guy?","how many people in the family?","how many planks","what do you call a grown boy4"];

var currentQuestion:int=0;

function displayQuestion():void{
question_tf.text=questionArray[currentQuestion];
}

checkAnswer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,checkAnswer);

function checkAnswer(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(answer_tf.text==answerArray[currentQuestion]){
    displayQuestion++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are attempting to show the next question when a question is answered correctly. However, what you are doing instead is trying to increment a variable named `displayQuestion`, which doesn't exist. I'm referring to this part of your code:

```
function checkAnswer(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(answer_tf.text==answerArray[currentQuestion]){
        displayQuestion++;
    }
}
```

You do however have a *function* named `displayQuestion`: as seen here in your code:

```
function displayQuestion():void{
    question_tf.text=questionArray[currentQuestion];
}
```

In addition, you stated that you remove the listener that validates the input, yet there is no function call to `removeEventListener` in the code you have shown.

After attempting to run your code in Flash CC 2014, creating the necessary `question_tf` and `answer_tf` textfield instances and `checkAnswer_btn` button instance, I get the following comipler errors:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 14, Column 20  1107: Increment operand is invalid.
>
> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 14, Column 5   1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Function to an unrelated type Number.

Did you receive any of these compiler errors? I would be surprised if you didn't experience the issue with the `displayQuestion` data type issue.

Based on your description, I can only assume you are instead trying to do the following:

```
var answerArray:Array=['uncle billy','six','178','hello4'];
var questionArray:Array=["what is the name of the guy?","how many people in the family?","how many planks","what do you call a grown boy4"];

var currentQuestion:int=0;

function displayQuestion():void{
    clearAnswerField();
    question_tf.text=questionArray[currentQuestion];
}

function clearAnswerField():void {
    answer_tf.text = "";
}

checkAnswer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,checkAnswer);

function checkAnswer(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(answer_tf.text==answerArray[currentQuestion]){
        currentQuestion++;
        displayQuestion();
    }
}

displayQuestion();
```

What the above code does, is corrects the issue with the function call to `displayQuestion`, increments the variable for which question to display and clears the answer field if the answer is correct.

There are however some very important things that need to be corrected, which your original code didn't account for:

1. Your `checkAnswer` function should also ensure that the index `currentQuestion` is never used when its value gets incremented past the number of questions that are available; otherwise, you'll get an array out of bounds exception when you try to access an element of `answerArray`
2. Your code should also be careful when checking answers with regards to case sensitivity. if someone enters "Uncle billy", your code will currently not accept the answer; however, you may want to accept that answer. the safe way to correct that is to do something like the following:

   ```
   if(answer_tf.text.toLowerCase() == answerArray[currentQuestion].toLowerCase() ) {
       currentQuestion++;
       displayQuestion();
   }
   ```

The code I created for you ran without issue in Flash CC 2014.

Comment: That was perfect!  Thanks for the assistance, I will start researching to determine the length of the array in order to advance to the final scene sequence.